# Laço for em Java

Tags: java, for

preciso receber um número n e então repetir o recebimento e processamento da string v, n vezes. Tentei fazer o seguinte:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Main {
    public static void main(String []args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    for(int x = 1; x < n; x++){
        String v = sc.next();
        int valorLed = 0;
        char [] numLed = { 6, 2, 5, 5, 4, 5, 6, 3, 7, 6 };
        char [] listV = v.toCharArray(); 
        int k = 0;
        int soma = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < listV.length; i++ ){
            k = (listV[i]-48);
            k = numLed[k];
            soma += k;
        }
        System.out.print(soma +" leds");
    }
}
    }
```

Porém, não funcionou. Como proceder? 
Por exemplo, se n for igual a 2, então receberei dois V's diferentes e imprimirei duas saídas diferentes.

Comment: "Não funcionou" é muito genérico. O que exatamente não funcionou? Dê mais detalhes do problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A linha for(int x = 1; x < n; x++)

Tem que ser x <= n 
for(int x = 1; x <= n; x++)

ou x iniciar de 0

for(int x = 0; x < n; x++)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("\nEntre com o valor de N :");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("\nNumero digitado :"+n);
        for(int x = 1; x <= n; x++){
            System.out.println("\nEntre com o valor de V passagem :"+x);
            String v = sc.next();
            int valorLed = 0;
            char [] numLed = { 6, 2, 5, 5, 4, 5, 6, 3, 7, 6 };
            char [] listV = v.toCharArray(); 
            int k = 0;
            int soma = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < listV.length; i++ ){
                k = (listV[i]-48);
                k = numLed[k];
                soma += k;
            }
            System.out.print("\n"+soma +" leds");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Então, mesmo assim, o código não é repetido n vezes

Comment: Esta passando sim 
é que você tem duas leituras de Teclado
veja o passo a passo que postei